# Regex Does Not Match as Expected

Tags: perl

**I am executing following code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $filter1="^p1c|^p2c|^p3c|^p11c|^p23c|^p105csi1m1|^p105csi1m2|^p105csi1m13|^p105csi2m14|^p101csi1m1|^p101csi1m2|^p101csi1m13|^p101csi2m14|^p103csi1m1|^p103csi1m2|^p103csi1m13|^p103csi2m16|^p102csi1m1|^p102csi1m2|^p102csi1m13|^p102csi2m16|^p100csi1m4|^p100csi1m5|^p100csi2m13|^p100csi1m14";
my $filter2="^p105csi2m13|^p105csi1m14";

$n1="p105csi1m14";

my $m1 .= "$n1 " if($n1 =~ m/$filter1/);
my $m2 .= "$n1 " if($n1 =~ m/$filter2/);

print "\nmatch 1 => $m1\n";
print "\nmatch 2 => $m2\n";
```

**The output from above code is as follow:**

```
match 1 => p105csi1m14

match 2 => p105csi1m14
```

**The expected result is as follow:**

```
match 1 => 

match 2 => p105csi1m14
```

I am not sure why it is behaving that way. Can someone please help resolve above issue?

Comment: `p105csi1m1` is a substring of `p105csi1m14`.

Comment: The regex `^p105csi1m1` matches your string. Did you intend to have a `$` at the end of the regex?

Answer (score 4):

You aren't defining the end of the match, and `p105csi1m1` is a substring of `p105csi1m14`.

The solution is to add a `$` to the regex to signify the end of the line.  Also, by using groups you can make it more readable and save yourself a lot of `^` and `$` characters.

```
my $filter1="^(p1c|...|p105csi1m1)$";
my $filter2="^(p105csi2m13|p105csi1m14)$";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's matching because it begins with p105csi1m1; that criterion appears in both filters you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You are making things difficult for yourself, for one thing. Your regex matches more than it should because it is only anchored at the start of the string. You need to anchor it at the end as well to avoid partial matches. Also, you have a lot of repeated text which can be simplified:

```
my @words = qw(p1c p2c p3c p11c p23c p105csi1m1 p105csi1m2 p105csi1m13 
               p105csi2m14 p101csi1m1 p101csi1m2 p101csi1m13 p101csi2m14 
               p103csi1m1 p103csi1m2 p103csi1m13 p103csi2m16 p102csi1m1 
               p102csi1m2 p102csi1m13 p102csi2m16 p100csi1m4 p100csi1m5 
               p100csi2m13 p100csi1m14);
my $filter1 = '^(?:' . join('|', @words) . ')$';
```

Although this is probably better solved with a hash lookup:

```
my %lookup = map { $_ => 1 } @words;   # create a key for each word
my $m1 .= "$n1 " if($lookup{$n1});     # check if key exists
```

Note that hash keys match exactly, so you will not have any flexibility that comes with regexes. But in this case, it looks like that is a good thing.